# django: VSCode not recognizing request.POST.get

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

> And in your views.py you can get the use input using the POST method
> `usergivenip = request.POST.get('textfield', None)`

i did this in my code and i got this error: "module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'POST'.
does this module not exist anymore or did it change? do i need to import something? (other than django.http.request)

Comment: import `django.http.request`? Why do you need to do that?? An `HttpRequest` instance is _passed_ as an argument to the view... Please show your view code.

Comment: You should provide your entire module code. It sounds like you've imported a module like `from django.http import request` and are using it in some incorrect way. The typical way you use `request.POST` is in a function or method which accepts a `request` parameter. I recommend you go through the official tutorial where [this topic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/) is covered.

Comment: found the problem, i was using request instead of HttpRequest. thanks for the help! also thanks for the tutorial, probably what i need.